# How do I refresh a github personal access token

Tags: javascript, jquery, github-api

I am trying to use github with a personal access token to fetch the content of a private repository. More specifically, the download link with the generated token is what I want. However, when I run this code, it fetches data fine but the token on the download link is not valid (it always gives me a 404). The same code in postman works just fine, however I noticed that the generated tokens change every time the api is called. However, I am not sure how to get that to work in vs code and its live server.

```
<body>

<div>
    <table class="table">
        <thead class="thead-dark">
            <tr>
                <th scope="col">Order</th>
                <th scope="col">Name</th>
                <th scope="col">Size</th>
                <th scope="col">Read</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>



<script>

    function get() {
        var myHeaders = new Headers();
        myHeaders.append("Authorization", "Bearer ghp_***********************");
       

        var requestOptions = {
            method: 'GET',
            headers: myHeaders,
            redirect: 'follow',
            origin: "Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *",

        };

        fetch("https://api.github.com/repos/Marko1990x/books/contents/", requestOptions)
            .then(response => response.json())
            .then(function (result) {

                var statusHtml = '';

                $.each(result, function (i, status) {
                    statusHtml += '<tr>';
                    statusHtml += '<td>' + i + '</td>';
                    statusHtml += '<td>' + status.name + '</td>';
                    statusHtml += '<td>' + status.size + '</td>';
                    statusHtml += '<td>' + "<a " + "href=" + status.download_url + '">' + "Click" + "</a>" + '</td>';
                    statusHtml += '</tr>';
                })

                $('tbody').html(statusHtml);

                console.log(result);
            })
            .catch(error => console.log('error', error));

    }

    get();

</script>
```

[image: how it looks when called]